# Retrieve all linked categories

Tags: mysql, query, recursive

I have Categories stored in a single table.

Where there is no limit on number of childerns.

I want to fetch all the linked categories for the provided category id:

The reason for getting the hierarchy is that I need to update the path field for each category that is either newly created or updated. I need to maintain the path field

Table name: `categories`

```
id  parentId    name    path                    isLastLevel     
1   0           Cat 1   Cat 1                   0
2   1           Cat 2   Cat 1 > Cat 2           0
3   2           Cat 3   Cat 1 > Cat 2 > Cat 3   1
4   0           Cat A   Cat A                   0
5   4           Cat B   Cat A > Cat B           1
```

Now I want to fetch all the hierarchy for `id: 3`

What I have tried so far is:

```
with recursive cte (id, name, parentId) AS (
    select
        id,
        name,
        parentId
    from
        categories
    where
        parentId = 1
    union
    all
    select
        c.id,
        c.name,
        c.parentId
    from
        categories c
        inner join cte on c.parentId = cte.id
)
select
    *
from
    cte;
```

The above query returns:

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        parentId: 0,
        name: Cat 1,
        path: Cat 1
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        parentId: 1,
        name: Cat 2,
        path: Cat 1 > Cat 2
    }
]
```

But I want this:

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        parentId: 0,
        name: Cat 1,
        path: Cat 1
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        parentId: 1,
        name: Cat 2,
        path: Cat 1 > Cat 2
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        parentId: 2,
        name: Cat 3,
        path: Cat 1 > Cat 2 > Cat 3
    }
]
```

If I provide `id: 2`, in that case I am expecting:

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        parentId: 0,
        name: Cat 1,
        path: Cat 1
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        parentId: 1,
        name: Cat 2,
        path: Cat 1 > Cat 2
    }
]
```

There is something that I am doing wrong with the query, can anyone identify?

**EDIT**

Here is reproduced scenario: https://dbfiddle.uk/llwsSBEu

Comment: Don't you need `WHERE ... = 2`?

Comment: @RickJames I am not getting your point

Comment: Welcome to [dba stackexchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/)
  Have a look at this: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example for database-related questions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @MarcelloMiorelli Question has been updated with the reproduction fiddle now

Answer (score 0):

In below script when your input is 1. It will return the child rows with their calculated paths.

```
WITH recursive cte (id, name, parentId, path)
AS (SELECT
          id,
          name,
          parentId,
          name AS path
    FROM  categories
    WHERE id = 1
    UNION ALL /*find the items where this is the parent for*/
    SELECT
         c.id,
         c.name,
         c.parentId,
         CONCAT(cte.path, '>', c.name) AS path
    FROM categories c
         INNER JOIN cte ON c.parentId = cte.id)
SELECT
         cte.id,
         cte.name,
         cte.parentId,
         cte.path
FROM     cte
ORDER BY id ASC;
```

In script below, you make use of the path column you have added in your demo script, but your input will be the destination and it will give the rows which have created this.

```
WITH recursive cte (id, name, parentId, path, pathfornext)
AS (SELECT
          id,
          name,
          parentId,
          CAST(path AS CHAR(1000)),
          CAST(REPLACE(path, CONCAT(' > ', name), '') AS CHAR(1000)) AS pathfornext
    FROM  categories
    WHERE id = 3
    UNION ALL /*find the items where this is the child for*/
    SELECT
         c.id,
         c.name,
         c.parentId,
         cte.pathfornext,
         CAST(REPLACE(cte.pathfornext, CONCAT(' > ', c.name), '') AS CHAR(1000)) AS pathfornext
    FROM categories c
         INNER JOIN cte ON c.Id = cte.ParentId)
SELECT
         cte.id,
         cte.name,
         cte.parentId,
         cte.path
FROM     cte
ORDER BY id ASC;
```

Comment: I need the hierarchy regarding the provided id. Can you please check my updated question. I added more details

Comment: In that case you would like to only move up, right? So If you say ID = 1, only 1 row will be returned, 2 will have 2 etc.?
I have edited the answer.

Comment: So my goal is to maintain the path column in the table

Comment: You would like to calculate the path instead of use the fixed columns?

Comment: I just want to calculate path e.g if I am going to create child of id: 1 with name of Cat X, so path should be: Cat 1 > Cat X

Comment: if I am going to create child of id: 2 with name of Cat Y, so path should be: Cat 1 > Cat 2 > Cat Y

Comment: OK, that one is clear ;-) And how about your input when selecting data. 
Do you give in Id 1. So you want all childs. In your case above Cat 1 > Cat X AND Cat 1 > Cat 2 AND Cat 1 > Cat 2 > Cat Y
Or, do you want to give in Cat Y and have returned
Cat 1
Cat 1 > Cat 2
Cat 1> Cat 2 > Cat Y

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140594/discussion-between-peter-and-stormtrooper).